# Drupal 7 Contextual Links Not working for a New User Group

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal 7 instillaled and i want them to be able to edit all block areas on the home page. The cog isnt showing up on any of the blocks.

I have "Use Contextual Links" checked in the user permissions and that still doesnt work.

Sorry for posting this question agian but i didnt get an an answer.

Regards,

Jacob

Comment: do you mean allowing a new role to edit blocks on the home page?

Comment: thats correct, so i have the generic ones that come with Drupal, thsoe being Administrator, and anonymous user and i  have created one called Editor. Im trying to set the permissions on that role to they can edit contextual links, but they cant, even though "Use contextual links" is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give them the necessary permissions to edit the blocks in that case, so that they can edit the content of the blocks, then is when they will be able to use contextual links.

Comment: im not 100 percent sure where to do this? there just normal blocks that i have created.

Comment: checkout the permissions page bro, or install some permissions module that would allow you to configure the permissions directly from the block admin page. Search drupal for modules, cant help you right now, gonna check tonight if you still havent got through. Regards

Comment: yeah i managed to get it workking, i just checked a few box's and now it works, i figured if the admin permissions allow it then i just go through and check them individtually to find one. thanks for your help